# Logistic regression with weighted variables

Tags: probability, logistic-regression

I want to fit a logistic regression model where predictor variables have different weights. Can I achieve this by not normalizing the variables?

For example let's say I have two predictor variables A and B. If the range of A is `[0,10]` and the range of B is `[0,20]` will my model give twice as much importance to B compared to A? If not, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give  $B$ twice of the weight of $A$, then you may consider to estimate the following model 
$$
\log\left(\frac{p}{1 - p} \right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1(A+2B)\quad (1)
$$
Or alternatively, you can estimate 
$$
\log\left(\frac{p}{1 - p} \right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1A+\beta_2B, \quad (2)
$$
and then to check the hypothesis $H_0: \beta_2 = 2\beta_1$ by comparing model $(1)$ with $(2)$ using the Deviance residuals.